# sfGuard and bhLDAPAuthPlugin in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, ldap, sfguard

I need to do the same functionality that do this pluggins together, well Authenticate LDAP way, and after save the user information in the local data base, to after give to that users some permisions,

Do you know some way to do the same functionality in symfony 2?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this bundle

http://symfohub.com/repo/FR3DLdapBundle

Thansk!!!